# SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue issue: Procedure or function X expects parameter @Y, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlcommand

I have a problem with the folowwing piece of code. I am passing a parameter (`List<SqlParameter>`) to a method executing the following code.

When it executes SQL Server throws an error saying that the proc expects a parameter that was not provided. I know this error and understand it, and when stepping through the code I can see that the `cmdExecuteReader` object has a collection of parameters with the correct name and value. What could be the problem?

```
     public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string storedProcedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
        {
                    SqlCommand cmdExecuteReader = new SqlCommand()
                    {
                        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                        Connection = conn,
                        CommandText = storedProcedure
                    };

                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
                        {
                            cmdExecuteReader.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.ParameterName, param.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        conn.Open();
                    return cmdExecuteReader.ExecuteReader();
       }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the `.Value` set to `null` for any of the parameters? If so, they aren't sent. Try:

```
cmdExecuteReader.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.ParameterName,
        param.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
```

(note the null-coalescing with `DBNull.Value`)

Also, note that `AddWithValue` may impact your query-plan re-use, as (for strings etc) it uses the length of the *value*. If you need maximum performance it is better to setup the parameter manually with the *defined* sizes.

Also note that *potentially* some of the parameters in the incoming list could be input-output, output or result. I would be very tempted to substitute for something more like:

```
SqlParameter newParam = cmdExecuteReader.Parameters.Add(
      param.ParameterName, param.SqlDbType, param.Size);
newParam.Value = param.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
newParam.Direction = param.Direction;
```

Comment: +1. I personally don't use AddWithValue, preferring to explicitly define the datatypes (and sizes) - otherwise you may end up with incorrect assumptions being made (such as .NET string values being passed in as NVARCHAR) which I get paranoid about

Answer (score 0):

I did the stuff that you are trying to do, here some examples:

```
public int ChangeState(int id, int stateId)
{
    return DbUtil.ExecuteNonQuerySp("changeDossierState", Cs, new { id, stateId });
}

public IEnumerable<Dossier> GetBy(int measuresetId, int measureId, DateTime month)
{
    return DbUtil.ExecuteReaderSp<Dossier>("getDossiers", Cs, new { measuresetId, measureId, month });
}
```

I recommend you to look [here](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20access%20layer%20%28ORM%29%20with%20the%20Value%20Injecter&referringTitle=Home)

and to download the samples solution (where there is a DAL Sample project included)
http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/